# Strange floating point comparison in python

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, floating-point

I am getting crazy with python float comparison logic, can you guys let me know what should I do to force python do the comparison correctly :

```
(Pdb) type( nonOverlaps[-1].end ) 
<type 'float'>
(Pdb) type(interv.start)
<type 'float'>
(Pdb) p nonOverlaps[-1].end
381690.887195
(Pdb) p interv.start
381682.616861
#So, nonOverlaps[-1].end is LARGER than interv.start
(Pdb) p nonOverlaps[-1].end <= interv.end
True
(Pdb) p nonOverlaps[-1].end < interv.end
True
#OMG, this comparison return value should be False
```

Comment: ???  What is interv.end ?

Comment: Ops, My bad... sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is a typo in your code. You're comparing nonOverlaps[-1].end to interv.end, when you should be comparing to interv.start.